# how to use firebase referral system in dart?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I want to implement the firebase dynamic links and reward the users if another user install from the referral link.

I was looking at the firebase documentation for this but how can we implement this in flutter as I don't see any packages for this.

I was looking at the issues mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11607) but there's no solution yet. If that's the case is there a way we can implement referral system or is it possible to do it as a method channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can now use the [firebase dynamic links](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) package from the dart packages and implement the referral system or reward users when they click on the links.